# How To Run Active X Objects in Non-IE Browsers?

Tags: html, vbscript, activex, client-side-scripting, system32

I want to access **System32** folders in html page WithOut **Server Side Script.**

And also run **Active X objects using Client side Scripts**

Comment: If you could do that, the internet would be a dangerous place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things to consider:

1. You should *never* do this
2. Seriously, never *ever* do this
3. No, really, I'm not kidding.  One slight mistake in your security model, and you will be the internet pariah of the year.  Do ***not*** do this.
4. If you're going to go ahead and do it anyway, you'll need an NPAPI plugin.  Note that Chrome has announced that they will eventually be dropping support for NPAPI -- we don't know how soon, and given that they haven't provided adequate solutions for a large number of problems currently solved by plugins I'm hoping it's not in the next couple of months, but once they do you'll need to use Native Client on Chrome, and NPAPI on the other ones. For an NPAPI plugin you could look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org), which is a framework that allows you to create a plugin that works both as NPAPI and ActiveX
5. Any option that will allow you to do this will require the user to download and install something.  There is no way around this, nor should there be.
6. Most web browsers run in user mode, i.e. not in administrator mode.  Generally when not in administrator mode you have -- at best -- read only access to the System32 directory.  If you need any better you'll have to launch another application that will request elevation and proxy commands to it from the plugin.

In short:

- This is a bad idea
- It's a pain in the neck
- It's really easy to make mistakes that would allow malicious attacks on users computers through your plugin.
- What you're talking about doing is really significantly more dangerous than I'm making it sound, but I don't know how to fully explain just how bad of an idea this would be.

Comment: I can able access **(system/32 Folders)** using **Vb-script** in client side... Is it Safety ?

Comment: not from a normal web page without enabling bunches of stuff